# Subsetting a dataframe based on summation of rows of a given column

Tags: r

I am dealing with data with three variables (i.e. id, time, gender). It looks like

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      time = c(21L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 27L, 3L, 4L, 10L),
      gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
    ),
    .Names = c("id", "time", "gender"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-12L)
  )
```

That is, each id has four observations for time and gender. I want to subset this data in R based on the sums of the rows of variable time which first gives a value which is greater than or equal to 25 for each id. Notice that for id 2 all observations will be included and for id 3 only the first observation is involved. The expected results would look like:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L ),
      time = c(21L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 27L ),
      gender = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
    ),
    .Names = c("id", "time", "gender"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-8L)
  )
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I really appreciate code to create data.frame and expected result. Very clearly explained question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to create a logical vector for each 'id', `cumsum(time) >= 25`, that is `TRUE` when the `cumsum` of 'time' is equal to or greater than `25`.

Then you can `filter` for rows where the `cumsum` of this vector is less or equal then `1`, i.e. filter for entries until the first `TRUE` for each 'id'.

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 filter(cumsum( cumsum(time) >= 25 ) <= 1)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id  time gender
#   <int> <int>  <int>
# 1     1    21      1
# 2     1     3      1
# 3     1     4      1
# 4     2     5      0
# 5     2     9      0
# 6     2    10      0
# 7     2     6      0
# 8     3    27      1
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `lag` of `cumsum` as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(id,gender) %>%
  filter(lag(cumsum(time), default = 0) < 25 )

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups: id, gender [3]
# id  time gender
# <int> <int>  <int>
# 1     1    21      1
# 2     1     3      1
# 3     1     4      1
# 4     2     5      0
# 5     2     9      0
# 6     2    10      0
# 7     2     6      0
# 8     3    27      1
```

Using `data.table`: (Updated based on feedback from @Renu)

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[,.SD[shift(cumsum(time), fill = 0) < 25], by=.(id,gender)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try dplyr construction:

```
dt <- groupby(df, id) %>%
#sum time within  groups
mutate(sum_time = cumsum(time))%>% 
#'select' rows, which fulfill the condition
filter(sum_time < 25) %>% 
#exclude sum_time column from the result
select (-sum_time)
```